# CodecRegistryError while running DJANGO commands

Tags: python, django, exception

i installed DJANGO in virtual environment and While running a command

```
manage.py runserver
```

as specified in starting of DJANGO tutorial
i'm facing this error.

```
(djangosite) E:\__FreshStart\Python\djnagosite\mysite>manage.py runserver   
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec     
File "c:\Python\VEnv\djangosite\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123      
    raise CodecRegistryError,\                                              
                        ^                                               
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- OS:Windows 7
- Python Installation:

  1. Python 2.7.6
  2. Virtual Environment for DJANGO based on python 2.7.6
  3. Python 3.4
- PYTHONPATH pointing to LIB under virtual environment folder
- PYTHONHOME is blank

Answer (score 0):

Cause: The multi installation in machine caused this issue... this happens if we are using the virtual environment

Resolution: May say it as a workaround...
!/usr/bin/python

delete this line and add the correct ENV var like PYTHONHOME PYTHONPATH